# Issues with jquery html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

Having some issues properly getting the manipulated data from an element. 
Everywhere on the internet doesn't seem to cover such a simple question with a simple answer. Please help.

I have manipulated an element with a returning ajax request:

```
$("#last_comment_added").html("1457856458")
```

now my function on the page:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var post_slug = $("#post_slug").html();
  var last_comment_added = $("#last_comment_added").text();

  if (post_slug && last_comment_added) {

    setInterval(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_comments.php",
        data: {
          "task": "updates",
          "post_slug": post_slug,
          "last_comment_added": last_comment_added
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
          eval(html)
        }
      });
    }, 10000);
  }
});
```

I get the old data from the element, not the new ajax "1457856458" data.

Please help.

Comment: Any error in the console? And why is that `eval(html)` hanging up in there? Log it to the console to see if you are getting the correct result.

Comment: No error. My code works fine. The problem is that it returns the OLD data (when the page initially loaded) and not the NEW data (after the ajax request). I suspect this is the DOM not being updated. I want to know if there is a way to update the DOM.

Comment: Ofcourse, just put the whole html you want to update in one div and then use the `.html()` function to change that particular div's content to the new one in the `success` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem right it's just that you create this variable called last_comment_added and expect it to be continually updated, you set it once to be the text of the last_comment_added, it's never updated in your interval function. Here's a change that should make it work better for you.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var post_slug = $("#post_slug").html();
 
  if (post_slug && last_comment_added) {

    setInterval(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_comments.php",
        data: {
          "task": "updates",
          "post_slug": post_slug,
          "last_comment_added": $("#last_comment_added").text()
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
          eval(html)
        }
      });
    }, 10000);
  }
});
```

Comment: Where did the initialization of `last_comment_added` go?

Comment: I took it out, instead each time you call the ajax you're pulling the text of the element with id last_comment_added at that time.

Comment: Here's your code `var last_comment_added = $("#last_comment_added").text();` last_comment_added is initialized  to the value of the element with last_comment_added as the ID, it's set a single time in your original code and it seemed to be that you were asking why it's not updated to the new value after you have an ajax query. I provided an answer that queries for the value you're passing to the ajax query when the query is being run. Try it out if it doesn't do what you want update your question with more details.

Comment: Thanks Gibs, if it's the correct answer then you can flag it as such so the question is shown as closed.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use eval.

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var post_slug = $("#post_slug").html();
    var last_comment_added = $("#last_comment_added").html();

    if (post_slug && last_comment_added) {

      setInterval(_update, 10000);

    }

});

function _update() {

   $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_comments.php",
        data: {
          "task": "updates",
          "post_slug": post_slug,
          "last_comment_added": last_comment_added
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {

            $("#last_comment_added").html(data)       

        }

    });

}
```

and you return from **PHP** only *NEW* data. (something like: `echo '1457856458';`)